# How to receive file when file is opened in python

Tags: python, macos, file, text-editor, finder

I am trying to create an app that could open files, like a text editor, in python. But I am running into a problem; I have no way of knowing what file to open. Ex. If I am on my Mac's Finder, and I want to open a file, my app should be an app I could open said file with. My first assumption was that it is passed as an argument when the app is launched. But after looking at the result of `sys.argv`, I don't see the file. It doesn't matter if I get the file path or the content of the file. I don't know how else to access it. Any help would be appreciated!

This is a base example of my code:

```py
import sys


# This doesn't work!
args = sys.argv
if len(args) > 1:
    file = args[1]
else:
    file = "No file was provided"
# -------------------------------

# Display file
```

(I am compiling my app using py2app, and using tkinter but am open to alternatives)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For tkinter, the `Tk()` root has functionality for capturing different events from the OS. The event for opening documents is `::tk::mac::OpenDocument`. To create a callback function to handle the event, use `createcommand('::tk::mac::OpenDocument', callback)`.

Here is a basic example:

```py
import tkinter

root = tkinter.Tk('Open File')

file_text = tkinter.Text(root)
file_text.pack()

def callback(*files):
    for f in files:
        # Open File and write it to the screen
        with open(f) as file:
            text = file.read()
            file_text.insert(tkinter.END , text)

root.createcommand('::tk::mac::OpenDocument', callback)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 3):

MacOS sends file open events to the application when opening a file by double clicking on it, or when you drop a file on the application icon.

Most GUI libraries have a way to receive such events and convert those to something you can process in Python.

What GUI library do you use? And what tool do you use to create an application bundle?

Comment: Thanks for the reply!! I am using Tkinter, but I am open to moving to alternatives. I am using py2app to bundle it

Comment: IDLE contains some code to handle file open events, see https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/09ffa69e2e84950751739ab500f820725e00a3dd/Lib/idlelib/macosx.py#L120

Comment: It works!! Using `Tk.createcommand` I can create a callback for events.

Answer (score 0):

for wxPython GUI apps

wx.App inherits from wx.PyApp;

Override PyApp.MacOpenFile

Its' signature is

```
def MacOpenFile(self, fileName):
```

Answer (score -1):

```
file = open("directory_to_file.txt", "r")
print(f.read())
```

f.read() will be the content of the file

Comment: This simply get's the content of the file. How would I get the file path when the app is launched?

Comment: So you want to select the file path when the program is running, like it pops up a window for you to choose the file?

Comment: I'm talking about double-clicking the file (do not worry about making my app open). If I double-click a .txt file, it will open in some sort of editor. I am also trying to do that. But I can't figure out *what* file to open

Comment: I see.... go to C forum for more infos, python wont really do it